# Why do Walkers' abilities change from season to season?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

In season 1 walkers can pick up rocks and break windows, climb fences and appear to look around. in later seasons they only walk and are easily distracted by noise. Why have their abilities changed?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the universe, but if it is only a loss of abilities it may represent a deterioration of the Walkers' bodies.

Comment: I don't remember walkers ever being able to pick up rocks or climb fences. What's your evidence?

Comment: @codeNinja At least two walkers pick up rocks and try to use them to [try to break down the door of the department store](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20101108195956/walkingdead/images/d/da/Zombies_attack_door.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

The Walkers can grab and turn door handles also in Season 1. For example, the mother keeps returning to her own house and scratching at the door, also turning the door handle to try to get in.

The loss of this ability can maybe attributed to them not feeding on a regular basis or from getting "dumber" as time goes on. They just regress to the primal mode of moving to the sound of food.